# Windows - Resize wallpapers UNLESS

Tags: resize, wallpaper

I have in Linux Mint a wallpaper-changer-script like the one below (running in crontab*). If you analyze it, it means that if the height or width of the random picture is greater than the screen width, then scale it ELSE do not scale it and just center it (there's a condition here).

And it works just great and I love my script. However, I cannot find something similar in Windows, I was wondering if anyone have a script just like that nearby instead of me having to code it?

The problem with windows wallpaper is that there's no option to NOT scale pictures below your width/height screen AND at the same time to scale pictures above your width/height at the same time. It's the same problem in Linux but that is why I made a script for this.

Please, don't answer about me having to resize images. I do not need to. I found the solution in Linux and of course it's possible to do this automatically in Windows. Just need a VBS or PowerShell script that will go into Task Scheduler.

*Crontab note for a 2m wallpaper change:

```
*/2 * * * *   bash /somewhere/wallpaper.sh
```

.

```
#!/bin/bash

DESKTOP=mate16
wallpaperFolder="your/wallpaper/folder/with/a/trailing/slash/"
wallpaperWidth="2560"
wallpaperHeight="1080"

# grab a random image
wallpaperImage="$(ls $wallpaperFolder | shuf -n1)"
wallpaperImage=$wallpaperFolder$wallpaperImage

# grab the width and the height of the picture
wallpaperWidth=`identify -format "%w" "$wallpaperImage" | tr -d ' '`
wallpaperHeight=`identify -format "%h" "$wallpaperImage" | tr -d ' '`


if [[ "$DESKTOP" = "gnome2" ]]; then
    gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "$wallpaperImage"
fi


if [[ "$DESKTOP" = "gnome3" ]]; then
    if [ $wallpaperImage_width -gt $wallpaperWidth -o $wallpaperImage_height -gt $wallpaperHeight ]; then
        DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options scaled
    else
        DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options centered
    fi
    DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:$wallpaperImage"
    DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color "#000000"
    DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color "#000000"
fi

if [[ "$DESKTOP" = "mate14" ]]; then
    if [ $wallpaperImage_width -gt $wallpaperWidth -o $wallpaperImage_height -gt $wallpaperHeight ]; then
        mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/picture_options scaled
    else
        mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/picture_options centered
    fi
    mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/picture_filename "$wallpaperImage"
    mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/primary_color "#000000"
    mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/secondary_color "#000000"
fi

if [[ "$DESKTOP" = "mate16" ]]; then
    matePID=$(pgrep mate-session)
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$matePID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)

    if [ $wallpaperImage_width -gt $wallpaperWidth -o $wallpaperImage_height -gt $wallpaperHeight ]; then
        DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.mate.background picture-options scaled
    else
        DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.mate.background picture-options centered
    fi
    DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.mate.background picture-filename "$wallpaperImage"
    DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.mate.background primary-color "#000001"
    DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.mate.background secondary-color "#000002"
fi


if [[ "$DESKTOP" = "xfce" ]]; then
    # image-style: 0=Auto, 1=Centered, 2=Tiled, 3=Stretched, 4=Scaled, 5=Zoomed
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-show -s false
    if [ $wallpaperImage_width -gt $wallpaperWidth -o $wallpaperImage_height -gt $wallpaperHeight ]; then
        xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-style -s 4
    else
        xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-style -s 1
    fi
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path -s "$wallpaperImage"
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-show -s true
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had to code the whole thing. Works pretty good, except in rare cases the Fit and Center gets mixed up.

**wallpaper-changer.vbs**

```
Dim shell,command
command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command ""C:\Scripts\wallpaper-changer.ps1"""
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command,0
```

**wallpaper-changer.ps1**

```
# https://gist.github.com/ivandeex/43477bdecb9ebd4e86fc328f81485e4f

# Installation
# Add C:\Scripts\wallpaper-changer.vbs
# Add C:\Scripts\wallpaper-changer.ps1
# Run in command line:
# schtasks /Create /TN "wallpaper-changer" /SC MINUTE /MO 2 /TR "C:\Scripts\wallpaper-changer.vbs"
# /MO 2 = change every 2 minutes

$wallPaperFolder = 'C:\your-picture-folder'




Function Update-Wallpaper {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Path,

        [ValidateSet('Center','Stretch','Fill','Tile','Fit')]
        $Style
    )
    Try {
        if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'Wallpaper.Setter').Type) {
            Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
            using System;
            using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
            using Microsoft.Win32;
            namespace Wallpaper {
                public enum Style : int {
                    Center, Stretch, Fill, Fit, Tile
                }
                public class Setter {
                    public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
                    public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
                    public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;
                    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
                    private static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
                    public static void SetWallpaper ( string path, Wallpaper.Style style ) {
                        SystemParametersInfo( SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange );
                        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true);
                        switch( style ) {
                            case Style.Tile :
                                key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "0") ; 
                                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "1") ; 
                                break;
                            case Style.Center :
                                key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "0") ; 
                                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ; 
                                break;
                            case Style.Stretch :
                                key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "2") ; 
                                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ;
                                break;
                            case Style.Fill :
                                key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "10") ; 
                                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ; 
                                break;
                            case Style.Fit :
                                key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "6") ; 
                                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ; 
                                break;
}
                        key.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
"@ -ErrorAction Stop 
            } 
        } 
        Catch {
            Write-Warning -Message "Wallpaper not changed because $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    [Wallpaper.Setter]::SetWallpaper( $Path, $Style )
}


# Get a random image file
$wallpaperRandom = Get-ChildItem -Path "$wallpaperFolder" -Recurse | Select-Object FullName | Get-Random -Count 1

# Get the width/height of the file
$wallpaperDetails  = New-Object -ComObject Wia.ImageFile
$wallpaperDetails.loadfile($wallpaperRandom.FullName)

# Get screen resolution
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Set wallpaper
If ( $wallpaperDetails.Width -gt [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width -Or $wallpaperDetails.Height -gt [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height ) {
  Update-Wallpaper -Path $wallpaperRandom.FullName -Style Fit
}
Else {
  Update-Wallpaper -Path $wallpaperRandom.FullName -Style Center
}
```